# How does startup.el work (on Debian 12)

Tags: start-up, bytecode

I'm using the `emacs/stable,stable,now 1:28.2+1-15` Debian package with Doom and am trying to change startup behavior. I made backups of `startup.el.gz` and `startup.elc` located at `/usr/share/emacs/28.2/lisp/`. After trying to change startup-behavior in vain I eventually deleted `startup.elc` entirely. When I try `emacs +2 anyfile` it still works flawlessly, despite the line-specifying functionality being implemented in lines 2440+ and 2578+ of `startup.el`. I verified that there was no emacs daemon running when executing the above command. What is going on here? How do I change startup behavior?

My end goal is allowing for negative line and column parameters which are counted from the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

startup.el and some others (see [loadup.el](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/loadup.el)) are loaded from a dumped Emacs, not from the Lisp files – that’s why your changes are not being reflected.

You’ll have make your changes and then either:

- Re-dump, and make sure to start Emacs with `--dump-file /path/to/your/new/dump`; or
- Build from source.

BTW, your init files are loaded before `command-line-1` is called, so there’s nothing preventing you from re-implementing it with your own handling of negative line numbers and columns.  Simply copy its definition to your `early-init.el` file and make whatever changes you like.

Comment: Thanks, I added my custom `command-line-1` to `early-init.el` but that doesn't affect `emacsclient`. Do you know how to address that? https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/79250/41212