# Custom `command-line-1` for `emacsclient`

Tags: emacsclient, command-line-arguments

I've put a custom definition of `command-line-1` in my `early-init.el` which works for for calling `emacs` but not for calling an `emacsclient`. How can I make it work in the latter case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`command-line-1` is entirely irrelevant to `emacsclient`.

If you want to modify emacsclient you need to edit and recompile [lib-src/emacsclient.c](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lib-src/emacsclient.c).